# How to adjust mongo aggregate to ignore duplicates in an unrelated field

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to adjust an aggregate command on MongoDB so that duplicates of a given field are ignored.  Here would be an example document:

```
{  
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
    "dev_type" : "Foo"
    "should_be_unique" : "abcdefg"
}
```

Right now my code searches for a count of the various "dev_types."  I want to leave that functionality intact while also reducing the count so that it does not count duplicates in the field "should_be_unique."

My existing Python code looks like this:

```
result_set = db.aggregate([
    {"$match": match_condition},
    {"$group": {"_id": {"dev_type": "$dev_type"},
                "total": {"$sum": 1}}}, ])
```

This returns results of this sort:

```
{ "_id" : { "dev_type" : "Foo" }, "total" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "dev_type" : "Bar" }, "total" : 7 }
```

I've tried a few options, but for the best of me I can't figure out the cleanest way to alter such a query while also eliminating duplicates.  The idea would be that if two documents had the same "should_be_unique" value, and both had "dev_type" set to "Bar," then the total for "Bar" would be 6 instead of 7, reducing as a result of the duplicate.

This seems like a common enough scenario for Mongo so I'm hoping there's a simple way to tune this query so that it yields the desired results.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$addToSet` to accumulate unique `should_be_unique` values in `$group` stage followed by `$project` with `$size` to count the values.

Something like

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": {"_id": {"dev_type": "$dev_type"},"unique": {"$addToSet": "$should_be_unique"}}},
    {"$project": { "total": {"$size": "$unique"}}}
])
```